# How to add type annotations to custom dict subclass in python?

Tags: python

I have a custom `dict` subclass that is similar to [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) but passes the missing key to `default_factory` so it can generate an appropriate value.

```py
class KeyDefaultDict(dict):
    __slots__ = ("default_factory",)

    def __init__(self, default_factory, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.default_factory = default_factory

    def __missing__(self, key):
        if self.default_factory is None:
            raise KeyError(key)
        ret = self[key] = self.default_factory(key)
        return ret

    def __repr__(self):
        return (
            f"{type(self).__name__}({repr(self.default_factory)}, {super().__repr__()})"
        )


d = KeyDefaultDict(int)
print(d["1"] + d["2"] + d["3"])  # out: 6
print(d)  # out: KeyDefaultDict(<class 'int'>, {'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3})
```

I wanted to add type annotations for this class like the rest of my project, but I couldn't find any example of how to do that.
I saw that the `typing` module uses external classes for adding annotations. For example, `defaultdict` would be annotated with `typing.DefaultDict` whose definition is `class typing.DefaultDict(collections.defaultdict, MutableMapping[KT, VT])`.

So it's an external class that subclasses `defaultdict` and the generic `typing.MutableMapping`.
However, I thought that they probably did it this way because they didn't want to change the original `collections.defaultdict`. I found examples of subclasses of `Generic` and `Mapping` but not classes that inherit from something else like `dict`.

The question is: How can I add type annotations for this class to make it a generic class?
Do I need to extend something else or make an external class for annotations?

I am using python 3.7.5 and I prefer to inherit directly from `dict` so I don't have to implement the required methods and for performance reasons.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I am very late but I just got this working in my own code base.

Basically, you need to use the typing [Mapping generic](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#defining-sub-classes-of-generic-classes)
This is the generic of what dict uses so you can define other types like `MyDict[str, int]`.

For my use-case, I wanted a special dict that formatted itself cleanly for logging but I will be using it all over
with various types so it needed typing support.

How to:

```
import typing

# these are generic type vars to tell mapping to accept any type vars when creating a type
_KT = typing.TypeVar("_KT") #  key type
_VT = typing.TypeVar("_VT") #  value type


# `typing.Mapping` requires you to implement certain functions like __getitem__
# I didn't want to do that, so I just subclassed dict.
# Note: The type you're subclassing needs to come BEFORE 
# the `typing` subclass or the dict won't work.
# I had a test fail where my debugger showed that the dict had the items,
# but it wouldn't actually allow access to them

class MyDict(dict, typing.Mapping[_KT, _VT]):
    """My custom dict that logs a special way"""
    def __str__(self):
        # This function isn't necessary for your use-case, just including as example code
        return clean_string_helper_func(
            super(MyDict, self).__str__()
        )

# Now define the key, value typings of your subclassed dict
RequestDict = MyDict[str, typing.Tuple[str, str]]
ModelDict = MyDict[str, typing.Any]
```

Now use you custom types of your subclassed dict:

```
from my_project.custom_typing import RequestDict #  Import your custom type

request = RequestDict()
request["test"] = ("sierra", "117")

print(request)
```

Will output as `{ "test": ("sierra", "117") }`